# Timer won't stop - .upstream.connect().cancel()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, timer, combine

I am trying to run a some code with a timer, and then stop the timer when some conditions are met.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
let updateTimer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

And the .onReceive

```
        .onReceive(updateTimer) { _ in
            
            if (story.status == "ready"){
                am.pollingFinished = true
                print("Update Timr Canceled (1)")
                updateTimer.upstream.connect().cancel()

            }
            
            if (am.pollingFinished) {
                print("Update Timr Canceled (2)")
                updateTimer.upstream.connect().cancel()

            }
```

Yet, as you can see from the following console prints, the time keeps running, even though the conditions are met

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZEsJ.png)

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the phrase `upstream.connect()` supposed to do?

Comment: Use Concurrency instead of Combine.

Comment: @Cy-4AH how would you do that with Timers? Do you have any code sample?

Comment: @OriC. Do you have a reproducible example demonstrating that a Timer does not cancel after cancel() is called on it? Unfortunately, I wasn't able to duplicate the behavior you described.

Comment: @DanielZhang hi Daniel, I posted the code in the root post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of auto connecting, you need to connect manually and store the resulting Cancellable. That is the object you later cancel. You will also need to subscribe to the Timer publisher explicitly. You do *not* need to keep a reference to the Timer publisher — just the Cancellable. You will find this a lot more tractable under SwiftUI if you keep the Timer Cancellable in a separate class object.

To be quite honest I don't see why you use a Timer publisher at all; personally, I would just use an actual Timer. However, if you insist on using a publisher, here's an example that illustrates the architecture I've just described:

```
class TimerManager: ObservableObject {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func makeTimerPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Date, Never> {
        let timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
        timerPublisher.connect().store(in: &cancellables)
        return timerPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    func stop() {
        cancellables.removeAll()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var timerManager = TimerManager()
    @State var labelText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(labelText)
            Button("Stop") { timerManager.stop() }
        }
        .onReceive(timerManager.makeTimerPublisher()) { labelText = String(describing: $0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am relatively new to SwiftUI. I have seen dozens of examples that look almost exactly like my code above, literally if you search for Timer tutorial for SwiftUI, this is what you get 99% of the time. So I was trying to figure out what's wrong with it. I might as well try your method but I thought this should be quite simple.

Comment: The examples I find are all about running a timer, but none of them mention _cancelling_ the timer. If you show me an example where it talks about cancelling the timer, we can think about how that differs from what you're doing. — Also, simple is as simple does; personally, I think what I wrote is simple.

Comment: Here is one: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer

Answer (score 1):

Example with Concurrency. All is quite simple:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!").task {
            do {
                for _ in 0..<5 {
                    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
                    print("timer fired")
                }
            } catch {
                print("timer cancelled")
            }
            print("timer done")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually show a mechanism for cancelling the "timer" here

Comment: @jnpdx it's loops condition obviously.

Comment: That will result in "timer done", but unless the view gets unloaded, "timer cancelled" is unlikely to ever happen, right?

Comment: @jnpdx it's just a example, change condition to whatever you like.

Comment: @Cy-4AH this is pretty neat, thank you. But how to you get .task to repeat? I don't want to use a loop, I want to use a condition to stop it. or replace the for with a while?

Comment: @OriC. yes you can replace `for` with `while !stop`